# Issue with tsvector search when using exclamation character

Tags: postgresql

I have a column (artist_name) containing names of artists in a table. I have another column (artist_name_search) which is auto populated by a trigger for full text search purpose.

The requirement is that when searching for the word "Pink", I should be able to retrieve the artists "Pink" and "P!nk". I'm able to query each of these artist names individually using ts_vector and ts_query but could not get the combined results when searching for the word "Pink"

Appreciate your help with solving this issue. Thanks!

```
--Definition of trigger that auto populates the tsvector column
CREATE TRIGGER artists_tsvector_search
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF artist_name
  ON artists
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    NEW.artist_name_search = to_tsvector('english',NEW.artist_name);
  END;

--Below query searches for the word "Pink"
select artist_name_search, artist_name from artists where to_tsquery('Pink') @@ artist_name_search

--Below query searches for the word "P!nk"
select artist_name_search, artist_name from artists where to_tsquery('P\!nk') @@ artist_name_search
```

Comment: I guess you won't be able to do that because the parser will already split `P!nk` into two lexemes.

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe!